# What is the "deployed" tab for in TFS 2012 Web Access

Tags: msbuild, tfsbuild

I have several build definitions setup in TFS 2012.  They all use Web Deploy and Web Packages and deploy to my dev and test servers and work just fine.

I can't, however, figure out what the "deployed" tab in TFS Web Access > Builds is used for?

Comment: I'm also very curious about the purpose of that tab. Was just googling about it and found nothing related.

Answer (score 2):

The 'deployed' tab seems to be related to Azure integration somehow.

I found [this post on the TFS Deployer](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/discussions/397983) website. It's even possible to mark a build as 'deployed' via PowerShell, which seems quite interesting. It would be nice to have our deployed builds showing in that tab, and by integrating with TFS Deployer this seems possible.