# TFS 2013 Web Access Deployed Tab

Tags: visual-studio-2012, azure, tfs, tfs-web-access

I'm trying to understand what the "Deployed" tab is used for in TFS 2013 Team Web Access. There's another similar question here: [What is the "deployed" tab for in TFS 2012 Web Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372508/what-is-the-deployed-tab-for-in-tfs-2012-web-access)

Some of the [information](http://tfsdeployer.codeplex.com/discussions/397983%22information%22) there seems to suggest that TFS Deployer is setting a build quality, but what is it? Another post indicates that it might be for Azure deployments.

Just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the "deployed" tab for in TFS 2012 Web Access](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17372508/what-is-the-deployed-tab-for-in-tfs-2012-web-access)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the built in Continious Build to Azure build template it will automatically set this for successfully deployments.

You may be able to set this through the API.

Comment: Thanks, Martin. By the way... love your work. You're a huge influence in terms of all things TFS.

Comment: This applies to VSO. TFS 2013 update 3 Web Access has this tab too but there is no Continous build to Azure template.